# Brownian motion start value

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, brownian-motion

Suppose the definition of a Wienerprocess without the assumption of $W_{0}=0$. 
Now I want to show that 
$Var[W_{t}-W_{s}]=E[(W_{t}-W_{s})^2]=t-s$ and 
$E[W_{t}-W_{s}]=0$ 
but I'm a bit stuck. Could anyone help me out?
So far I have for the first one:
$E[(W_{t}-W_{s})^2]=E[(W_{t}-W_{0})^2]+E[(W_{s}-W_{0})^2]-2E[(W_{t}-W_{0})(W_{s}-W_{0})]=t+s- ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $B_t := W_t-W_0$ is a Brownian motion started at $0$. Since $W_t-W_s = B_t-B_s$, we find

$$\mathbb{E}(W_t-W_s) = \mathbb{E}(B_t-B_s) = 0$$

and

$$\mathbb{E}((W_t-W_s)^2) = \mathbb{E}((B_t-B_s)^2)=t-s$$

where we have used that $B_t-B_s \sim B_{t-s} \sim N(0,t-s)$ for any $s \leq t$.

Comment: @RoosJansen I already used that; for instance for the first one I used that $\mathbb{E}(B_t)=0$ which is equivalent to saying that $\mathbb{E}(W_t-W_0)=0$. (Note that there is no need to expand the square $(W_t-W_s)^2$ as you did; it's much easier to use the stationarity of the increments!)